# При попытке через крон записать значения и передать их заббиксу в файле только пробел

Tags: linux, zabbix

Пытаюсь через крон записать значения и передать их заббиксу.

```
* * * * * fping -q -c 1 1.2.3.4 2>&1 | cut -d '/' -f9 > /tmp/pingresult
```

В файле появляется размер 1к и внутри ничего нет, точнее пробел. Если выполняю команду в консоли в файле появляются нужные данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему решением от самого заббикса. Нужно было указать в конфиге сервера где расположен fping и тогда заббикс шлет всё корректно прямо в график, с созданной переменной pingicmp.

Answer (score 0):

в файл `crontab` лучше и надёжнее записывать вызов программ/скриптов.

а уже внутри этих программ/скриптов реализовывать требующуюся функциональность.

Comment: не помогло. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: 1. убедитесь, что вы запускаете скрипт от имени того же пользователя, от которого запускаются команды из редактируемого вами файла `crontab`. 2. попробуйте запусить скрипт с теми же значениями переменных окружения, которые используются при выполнении заданий из того же файла.

Comment: 1. Cron рутовый. 2. Если запустить из консоли файл, отрабатывает нормально, так же если вбить команду так же отрабатывает нормально. 3. Эта штука работает нормально на Ubuntu, не работает на Gentoo.

Comment: … 2. попробуйте запустить скрипт с теми же значениями переменных окружения, которые используются при выполнении заданий из того же файла (**`crontab`**).

Comment: не понимаю можно команду примера привести.

Comment: так туда же, прямо в начало скрипта допишите все переменные окружения, которые присваиваются `cron`-ом при вызове заданий. а чтобы очистить окружение от текущих переменных, можно вызвать скрипт так: `$ env -i /путь/к/скрипту`

Comment: узнать же, какие именно переменные окружения и с какими значениями передаёт `cron` вашим заданиям, можно с помощью «задания» `env > /файл/куда/сохранить`

Comment: команда `env` служит для получения текущих переменных окружения.

Comment: ах, да, перечисляя критерии для воспроизведения неправильного поведения, я совсем упустил из виду, что *cron* для выполнения заданий использует, скорее всего, не тот *shell*, в котором вы проверяете работу скрипта.